# Xcode7 ConcurrencyDebug concurrency violations when reading properties?

Tags: ios, core-data, concurrency

It seems like in Xcode7 with the `-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug` switch turned on, multi threading violations happen even if you are only reading a property. Is this expected behavior now?

```
-(NSManagedObjectContext *)newPrivateManagedObjectContext
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *newContext = 
    [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType>];
    [newContext setParentContext:<some shared MOC with NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];

    return newContext;
}

-(void)someMethod 
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self newPrivateContext];
    NSManagedObject *mo = [context objectWithID:objectID]; // concurrency voilation
    // assuming the above worked you would still get
    if (mo.someProperty == nil) // also a concurrency violation 
    {
    }
}
```

Currently it seems like Xcode is expecting us to write every single interaction with an `NSManagedObjectContext` in a `performBlock*` block. Maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's expected. You're using `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`, which means you **must** use either `performBlock:` or `performBlockAndWait:` **every** time you do something that uses the context. That includes any method calls on the context (your call to `objectWithID:` for example). It also includes any calls on any other object managed by the context-- such as looking up the value of a property on an object fetched from the context.

In short: This is exactly what should happen, because you're not using the managed object context correctly.

Comment: Tom -- thanks for the quick response. I was _sure_ I read years ago that blocks were only needed when assigning properties.I can still see parts of the article in my mind...just can't remember which one it was. I'm going to go sit in the back of the class for a while. :-/

Comment: @memmons - Can't believe everything you read... even on SO ;-)  But, you can believe what Tom said.

Comment: @JodyHagins Indeed, I'm aware of Tom's qualifications. This situation reminds me of a few months ago when I learned that peanut butter is not, in fact, green (apparently a common mistake for people who are red/green colorblind like me). I'll file this under "things I assumed were true but that were absolutely were not."